# Is there a global index for all currencies?

Tags: foreign-exchange

I've recently found the need to convert USD to CAD, so I just started following foreign exchange rates for the first time. In the past few days, USD/CAD dropped. However, it's hard to tell if CAD appreciated or if USD depreciated. In this case, it seems like USD depreciated.

Is there a global index that I can compare individual currencies to?

Answer (score 2):

*The Economist's*  [Big Mac index](http://www.economist.com/content/big-mac-index) does.

Answer (score 1):

Loaded question: all currency's "value" is based on their relative value to a basket of currencies. This holds true whether the central bank of that currency is pegging/fixing or in any other way controlling the value currency against a particular other currency.

Your best insight will be to monitor all of the popularly traded currency pairs for your reference currency.

For a US Dollar centric view, some services such as finviz have an easy to glance at view

http://finviz.com/futures_charts.ashx?t=CURRENCIES&p=d1

But, you can also follow Euro/CAD spot and futures markets if you wanted to, for example

And finally, there may be an index that actually does track the changes of your reference currency, based on a portfolio of multiple other currencies.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr; There are such indices, but no one is perfect. I go with SDR (XDR) for simplicity.

If you want inflation-adjusted, i.e. an index that will also take into account "global" inflation I found only one: [World Currency Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WCU_%E2%80%93_World_Currency_Unit) from Lingnan University, Hong Kong. Although they publish updated rates daily it looks a bit rusty and almost nobody seems to reference it. Besides there's no real API for it.

If you don't care about the inflation the simplest one to follow would be [Special Drawing Rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_drawing_rights) from IMF. Many currency exchange sites include it rates and because of that it makes it easier to use than others.

There are other currency-basket indices that include more currencies including:

- [WOCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOCU) from not-for-profit WDX Institute,
- [FTSE WPU](http://www.ftse.com/products/indices/WPU) index, but unfortunately no ETF seems to follow it.

I personally pick XDR for simplicity.

Note that there's no one, global definition of "value". Say for example that you owe 1% of global wealth and because of productivity increase prices dropped for every service and products requiring human work. Are you more rich? You still owe 1% of total wealth, but you can buy more with it. Even if the answer is "yes, I'm more rich". How much richer are you?